# 'Type' is not an Array type with Context

Tags: reactjs, typescript, next.js

i'm new to TypeScript and i'm getting an error preventing me from building the app.
It works fine locally but when i try to build it i get an error.

This is my context file:

```
import React, {
  useState,
  Dispatch,
  SetStateAction,
  createContext,
} from "react";

type Props = {
  children: JSX.Element;
};

type Filters = {
  type: string[];
  rating: number[];
  facilities: string[];
  stars: number[];
  minPrice: number;
  maxPrice: number;
};

type UserContextType = {
  filters: {};
  setFilters: Dispatch<SetStateAction<Filters>>;
};

const iUserContextState = {
  filters: {
    type: [],
    stars: [],
    rating: [],
    facilities: [],
    minPrice: 0,
    maxPrice: 0,
  },
  setFilters: () => {},
};

export const FilterContext = createContext<UserContextType>(iUserContextState);

export function FilterComponent({ children }: Props) {
  const [filters, setFilters] = useState<Filters>({
    type: [],
    stars: [],
    rating: [],
    facilities: [],
    minPrice: 0,
    maxPrice: 0,
  });
  return (
    <FilterContext.Provider value={[filters, setFilters]}>
      {children}
    </FilterContext.Provider>
  );
}

export default FilterComponent;
```

However in my filter component where i use the context i get an error saying: Type 'UserContextType' is not an array type.

Anybody have an idea what i'm doing wrong?

Thanks!

Comment: what @Mathias Falkenberg  mentioned plus `type UserContextType = { filters: Filters; setFilters:...};`

Answer (score 2):

Well, 'UserContextType' *is* not an array type...

This line: `value={[filters, setFilters]}` is setting the value of the provider to an array (`[ ]`) containing the elements `filters` and `setFilters`.

What you need is an *object* containing `filters` and `setFilters` members. To achieve that, replace the square brackets with curly brackets like: `value={{filters, setFilters}}`

Comment: hi, thanks for your reply. Alright, i understand that part. But when i change it to being an object i get an error in my filter component -> Object is not iterable. Altough i'm not trying to iterate through "filters". I'm just setting an object to it. A filter object which holds arrays.

Comment: This did not work for me

Comment: I am not able to reproduce the error you describe. But it could be because `filters` in your `UserContextType` is defined as `{}` (an object with no properties - which essentially makes it non-iterable). Did you mean to make it `filters: Filters`?